# How do I remove dry lube with teflon from wood cabinets before painting?

Tags: cleaning, repainting

I've been painting some wood cabinets from our kitchen for a ridiculously long time now. Without getting into it, they've been a bear.

My husband got some "b'laster dry lube with teflon" on them and they definitely need another coat of paint but are covered with this dry lube. How do I get it off?

I've tried TSP-PF solution, denatured alcohol and sanding but I'm pretty sure there's still lube on there. Manufacturer suggests "standard prep solvent" - but I'm not sure what that means. Help!

Comment: Ask the manufacturer what they mean by "standard prep solvent": there are many solvents one may use for many processes. They should be able to point you to a specific substance. But the correct solvent to break through the grease is the correct thing to use to clean it up. Note that the solvent may be dangerous to touch and breathe, also get decent safety equipment and a good air cross-ventilation.

Comment: Is this dry lube for the hinges?  If do  its graphite powder and difficult to clean up. Can you post a picture please

Answer (score -1):

Removing dry lube with Teflon from wood cabinets before painting can be a bit tricky, as Teflon-based lubricants are designed to be long-lasting and resistant to many solvents. However, here are steps you can follow to try and remove the lubricant:

Materials You'll Need:

1. Rubbing Alcohol or Acetone: These solvents can help break down Teflon. Test them in an inconspicuous area first to ensure they won't harm your cabinets' finish.
2. Clean Rags or Paper Towels: For wiping and scrubbing.
3. Plastic Scraper or Putty Knife: To gently scrape away any residue.
4. Fine Grit Sandpaper (Optional): If the lubricant is very stubborn, you may need to lightly sand the surface.

Steps:

1. Test in an Inconspicuous Area: Before attempting any cleaning method, it's essential to test the solvent you plan to use on an inconspicuous area of the wood to ensure it won't damage the finish.
2. Apply Rubbing Alcohol or Acetone: Dampen a clean cloth or paper towel with rubbing alcohol or acetone. Gently rub the affected area. Avoid excessive rubbing or scrubbing to prevent damaging the wood finish.
3. Use a Plastic Scraper or Putty Knife: If the lubricant is softened but not coming off entirely, use a plastic scraper or putty knife to gently scrape away the residue. Be very careful not to scratch the wood.
4. Repeat as Needed: You may need to repeat the process several times, applying the solvent and gently scraping until the lubricant is mostly gone.
5. Light Sanding (if necessary): If the lubricant residue is stubborn and won't come off with solvents alone, you can try using a very fine grit sandpaper (around 400-600 grit) to lightly sand the affected area. Sand very gently to avoid damaging the wood finish. After sanding, clean the area thoroughly.
6. Clean Thoroughly: Once you've removed the lubricant residue, clean the entire cabinet surface with a mild soapy solution and water to remove any remaining solvent residue. Rinse with clean water and dry thoroughly.
7. Prime and Paint: After you've cleaned the cabinets, you should be ready to prime and paint. Make sure to use a good-quality wood primer before applying paint to ensure proper adhesion and a smooth finish.

Always work in a well-ventilated area when using solvents, and follow safety precautions mentioned on the solvent's container. Additionally, wear appropriate personal protective equipment, such as gloves and eye protection, when working with solvents and sandpaper.

Comment: I have tidied it up, but cant decide if it csme ftom chatgpt.

Comment: Downvoted for obvious chatgpt.